# How can i update the datas in Content node in umbraco using C#?

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have the id of that node and i need to update the fields in that node using an alias name.
I found _contentService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus to create new node but i need a particular node to updated than duplication

Comment: Which version of Umbraco is this for?

Comment: @Tim, 
Umbraco version 7.12.4 assembly: 1.0.6879.21982

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following:

```
var myContent = _contentService.GetById(YOUR_NODE_ID_HERE);

myContent.SetValue("PROPERTY_ALIAS_HERE", "YOUR_VALUE_HERE");

_contentService.SaveAndPublish(myContent);
```

Which would update a property and save and publish it. You can update as many properties as you like. Obviously SetValue may be more complicated if the property you are setting is  something more than a basic type (e.g. text/number). The documentation for the content service can be found here: https://our.umbraco.com/apidocs/v7/csharp/api/Umbraco.Core.Services.IContentService.html